# How to add value to custom Input Field in React Table Library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7, react-table-v6

I have created a *products* table. The table has an input field for quantity where the user can add a quantity for a specific product and then add it to the cart.

However, when I type in the input field the values keep disappearing. I was able to get the added product with quantities but still, if input fields stay empty it won't make sense.

```jsx
const [itemQuantity,setItemQuantity] = useState([]);
```

How can I provide the input field value attribute from the item quantity Array State?

This code shows how I am getting quantities including the Product Object.

```jsx
const handleQuantites = (newValue) => {
    let found = false;
    let newItems = [...itemQuantity];
    if (itemQuantity.length > 0) {
      for (let index = 0; index < newItems.length; index++) {
        if (newItems[index].code === newValue.code) {
          newItems[index].Quantity = newValue.Quantity;
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        return setItemQuantity(newItems);
      }
      setItemQuantity([...itemQuantity, newValue]);
    } else {
      setItemQuantity([...itemQuantity, newValue]);
    }
  };

  const BundleColums = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Bundle Name",
        accessor: "name",
      },
      {
        Header: "Bundle Category",
        accessor: "categoryName",
      },
      {
        Header: "Bundle Status",
        accessor: "status",
      },
      {
        Header: "Quantity",
        accessor:"Quantity",
        Cell: ({ cell }) => (
          <Fragment>
            <input
              type={"text"}
              placeholder="Add Quantity b"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleQuantites({
                  ...cell.row.original,
                  Quantity: e.target.value,
                });
              }}
              min={0}
            />
          </Fragment>
        ),
      },

      {
        Header: "Actions",
        Cell: ({ cell }) => (
          <Fragment>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary "
              onClick={() => {
                handleAddToCart(cell.row.original);
              }}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>
          </Fragment>
        ),
      },
    ],

    [itemQuantity]
  );
```

Image of what my table looks like:

[image: As I keep adding Quantity it keeps disappearing]

As I keep adding Quantity it keeps disappearing!

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to share the section of your code that shows the source of your react-table rows data; I want to know what properties exist in the objects of your array.

Comment: @AminMashayekhan  thankyou for your response , i sorted out that problem , however i am facing another problem , i want to call a function from react-table but it not called


      
        Header: "Actions",

        Cell: ({ cell }) => (
          
            <div>
              <button
           
                onClick={() => {
                 
                  handleRemove(cell.row.original);
                }}
              >
                Remove Item
              </button>
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, if you try it according to the example below, it might work as you want:

```js
      {
        Header: "Quantity",
        accessor:"Quantity",
        Cell: ({ cell }) => (
          <Fragment>
            <input
              type={"text"}
              placeholder="Add Quantity b"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleQuantites({
                  ...cell.row.original,
                  Quantity: e.target.value,
                });
              }}
              value={cell.row.original.Quantity}
              min={0}
            />
          </Fragment>
        ),
      },
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You can add the state value to the input `<input ... value={<PUT STATE HERE>} />` It will auto-update on state changes. Check out [https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#:~:text=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20value%3D%7Bthis.state.value%7D%20onChange%3D%7Bthis.handleChange%7D%20/%3E](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#:%7E:text=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20value%3D%7Bthis.state.value%7D%20onChange%3D%7Bthis.handleChange%7D%20/%3E)